"JasperReports: How to Prevent Repeated Text in Detail Section When Using a Table in the Summary Section?"
I am using JasperReports to generate a report, and I have encountered an issue where text in the detail section of the report is being repeated for every row in the table within the summary section. This repetition results in unwanted overlapping text and visual clutter in the final report output.
Report Structure:

Detail Section: Contains a piece of text that appears for each row.

Summary Section: Displays a table with multiple rows of data (e.g., id, last_name).


The problem occurs because the text in the detail section is being displayed multiple times—once for each row in the table—leading to an issue where the text overwrites the content of the table and creates confusion in the report layout.

Placing the text in the detail section: This causes the text to repeat for each row in the table.

Placing the text in the column header: This eliminates the repetition, but the column header is not large enough to accommodate all the text I need to display.

Goal: I want to find a solution where the text appears only once in the report (without repetition for each row in the table) while being able to display all of my text in a readable way. The text should be placed in an appropriate area of the report, such as the header or another section, without being restricted by the column header size.



One of the cases where a picture could help understanding the problem.., Have you tried to uncheck 'Print repeated values' or to use a PrintWhen-Expression with the REPORT_COUNT using the text in the details

Or even better: post a minimal, reproducible example

It works this $V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1 (added in details)
